# Limit 1 by each group in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want top 1 (first) date for each group in MySQL.

```
SELECT id, date FROM t1 ORDER BY date LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You can go to dbfiddle.uk and set up your table(s) with some sample data and try a query or two there - show us that you've at least tried something! Post the fiddle link back here along with the tables and data - help us to help you! Please alwways include your **version** of MySQL - very important for any answers. Hint: window functions are your friend!

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW thank you. I am using MySQL version 5.7.33-36 and window Functions aren't working. Any solution that I could use Window Functions for this version?

Comment: Well, since I don't know what your problem is, I can't answer that! Please do what I suggested - go to dbfiddle.uk, put in your table(s), some sample data and your desired result! Then put all that information back into the question and you'll receive an answer quickly enough!

Comment: See the added tag.  Also see stackoverflow.com